# Connect ReactJS to other Docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have 7 container. 1 frontend, 4 backend, and 2 database.
This is my docker-compose

```
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.192.0/20
          gateway: 192.168.192.1
```

And this for backend

```
networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.192.4
```

This is .env for ReactJS (frontend)

```
REACT_APP_API_AUTH_HOSTNAME=http://192.168.192.4:4000
```

But it doesn't work. Because when I open in browser with my pc, frontend app keep trying to post to that private ip. How can i connecting ReactJS to post to its local ip address?

Answer (score 0):

you need to map ports in your docker compose. something like this:

```
kibana:
 image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.2
 ports:
  - "5601:5601"
```

Comment: map port need to know public ip in frontend. I need frontend can access backend with private ip

Comment: You can't access that container-private IP address directly except one one very specific setup (the browser and Docker are running on the same physical host and it's running native Linux).  You need to publish ports as shown here and use the host's IP address or DNS name.

Comment: @DavidMaze But if i use ports like that, i must rebuild ReactJS to use in other server. Because ReactJS can't read .env file after npm run build.